# Find multiple matches in a dataset, and return all matches in a single row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

What array formula would work for this?

**Test Sheet:** [Open](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13BAsgML2S_JCIyPCPOKalomm0ldm9AUU5jSE3AybM7o/edit?usp=sharing)

**Current Data Structure**

- Contains a running list of names and when they started, ended training.

```
|   A   |     B      |     C    |
| John  | StartDate1 | EndDate1 |
| Adam  | StartDate3 | EndDate3 |
| John  | StartDate2 | EndDate2 |
| Ted   | StartDate5 | EndDate5 |
| Adam  | StartDate4 | EndDate4 |
```

**Expected Results**

- Unique column of names in column E `=UNIQUE(A2:A)`
- Next to the unique name, display every StartDate & EndDate that matches the unique name.

```
|   E   |     F      |     G    |     H      |     I    |
| John  | StartDate1 | EndDate1 | StartDate2 | EndDate2 |
| Adam  | StartDate3 | EndDate3 | StartDate4 | EndDate4 |
| Ted   | StartDate4 | EndDate4 |            |          |
```

**What I have tried**

`=FILTER(B2:C,A2:A = E2)`

- Does not return on a single row. ❌
- Does not work with ARRAYFORMULA. ❌

`=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:C,A2:A = E2:E))`

- Returns all StartDates on a single row, and all End Dates on the next row. ❌

  - *It should return on a single row (StartDate,EndDate,StartDate,EndDate, etc)*
- Does not work with ARRAYFORMULA. ❌

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E2:E,A2:C,{2,3}))`

- Returns the first match only ❌
- Works with array formula. ✔️

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better arrayformula that can display every start and end date that matches a unique name in a row?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(IF(A3:A="",,{A3:A, "×"&B3:B&"×"&C3:C}), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))
```

[image]

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you player0! This worked exactly as needed.